# Is there a way I can use Python's cumsum() until a certain condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I would like to do running totals using `cumsum()`, until a certain condition is met. In my case, i want to accumulate values until I see a negative value, then reset to 0. Here is my dataset;

```
Name    Date    Amount
ABC 4/30/2020   0
ABC 5/31/2020   2500
ABC 6/30/2020   0
ABC 7/31/2020   0
ABC 8/31/2020   0
ABC 9/30/2020   0
ABC 10/31/2020  0
ABC 11/30/2020  0
ABC 12/31/2020  -1925
ABC 1/31/2021   0
ABC 2/28/2021   0
ABC 3/31/2021   0
```

I tried to use `df['Rolling_Amount'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Amount'].cumsum()`. But it does not reset after seeing a negative amount. Here is what I get;

```
Name    Date    Amount  Rolling_Amount
ABC 4/30/2020   0       0
ABC 5/31/2020   2500    2500
ABC 6/30/2020   0       2500
ABC 7/31/2020   0       2500
ABC 8/31/2020   0       2500
ABC 9/30/2020   0       2500
ABC 10/31/2020  0       2500
ABC 11/30/2020  0       2500
ABC 12/31/2020  -1925   575
ABC 1/31/2021   0       575
ABC 2/28/2021   0       575
ABC 3/31/2021   0       575
```

However, I would like to reset my counter to 0 after *Amount* -1925. Expected output should look like

```
ABC 4/30/2020   0       0
ABC 5/31/2020   2500    2500
ABC 6/30/2020   0       2500
ABC 7/31/2020   0       2500
ABC 8/31/2020   0       2500
ABC 9/30/2020   0       2500
ABC 10/31/2020  0       2500
ABC 11/30/2020  0       2500
ABC 12/31/2020  -1925   0
ABC 1/31/2021   0       0
ABC 2/28/2021   0       0
ABC 3/31/2021   0       0
```

Comment: What do you expect for the last three dates?

Comment: Can you put what your _desired_ output looks like in addition to the wrong output you're currently getting?

Comment: @HenryEcker I have updated the desired output. Thanks

Comment: @HenryEcker, the solution works well. Thank you for your assistance. I was really stuck. If I want to also group by 'Name'. How would I do that in the script you recommended. Incase when I do this again, i might want to group by "Name" and then the positive and negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

Let's Try to create a boolean index to detect when numbers go from either positive to negative, or negative to positive to delimit groups, then get the cumsum for each group:

```py
m = df.Amount.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
df['Rolling_Amount'] = df.Amount \
    .groupby((m < 0).eq((m > 0).shift()).cumsum()) \
    .cumsum() \
    .mask(lambda s: s < 0, 0)
```

Sample Input:

```
Name    Date    Amount
ABC 4/30/2020   0
ABC 5/31/2020   2500
ABC 6/30/2020   0
ABC 7/31/2020   50
ABC 8/31/2020   0
ABC 9/30/2020   -1925
ABC 10/31/2020  0
ABC 11/30/2020  100
ABC 12/31/2020  0
ABC 1/31/2021   200
ABC 2/28/2021   0
ABC 3/31/2021   0
```

Output:

```
   Name        Date  Amount  Rolling_Amount
0   ABC   4/30/2020       0               0
1   ABC   5/31/2020    2500            2500
2   ABC   6/30/2020       0            2500
3   ABC   7/31/2020      50            2550
4   ABC   8/31/2020       0            2550
5   ABC   9/30/2020   -1925               0
6   ABC  10/31/2020       0               0
7   ABC  11/30/2020     100             100
8   ABC  12/31/2020       0             100
9   ABC   1/31/2021     200             300
10  ABC   2/28/2021       0             300
11  ABC   3/31/2021       0             300
```